# ¿Cómo crear una lista de búsqueda?

Tags: javascript

Quiero crear una lista de busqueda que funcionara como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté lo siguiente utilizando [una lección de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp) pero no funciona. Cuando escribo cosas en la barra de búsqueda, no filtra nada en la dinámica e incluso cuando hago Enter.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <p>
       <label>Text box</label>
       <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
 </p>

 <p id="txtOut"></p>
</body>

<script>
fetch('https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    var divOut = document.getElementById('txtOut');
    var allStudents = myJson.students;
    var txtOut = "";
    for (var k in allStudents) {
      txtOut += `<b>${allStudents[k].firstName}</b><br />`;
      txtOut += `email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Average: ${allStudents[k].grades}<br />`;
      txtOut += `<img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"><hr />`;
    }
    divOut.innerHTML = txtOut;
  });

function search() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("txtOut");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Además, si saben reproducir el css me interesa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es utilizar los `dataset`. Y ya puestos, en lugar de una serie de *párrafos*, vamos a crear una lista no ordenada `<ul>` a la que añadiremos los elementos `<li>`, lo cual es más acorde al tipo de dato que estás manejando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <p>
       <label>Text box</label>
       <input type="Search for names" id="myInput" onkeyup="search()" placeholder="Search for names..">
 </p>

 <ul id="txtOut"></ul>
</body>

<script>
fetch( 'https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students' )
  .then( function( response ) {
    return response.json( );
  } )
  .then( function( myJson ) {
    const divOut = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
    var allStudents = myJson.students;
    for( let k in allStudents ) {
      let txtOut = '';
      let listItem = document.createElement( 'li' );

      // Añadimos el nombre como parte del dataset.
      listItem.dataset.nombre = allStudents[k].firstName.toUpperCase( );

      txtOut += `<b>${allStudents[k].firstName}</b><br />`;
      txtOut += `email: ${allStudents[k].email}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Company: ${allStudents[k].company}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Skill: ${allStudents[k].skill}<br />`;
      txtOut += `Average: ${allStudents[k].grades}<br />`;
      txtOut += `<img src="${allStudents[k].pic}"><hr />`;

      listItem.innerHTML = txtOut;
      divOut.appendChild( listItem );
    }
  } );

function search() {
  const prefix = document.getElementById( 'myInput' ).value.toUpperCase( );
  const ul = document.getElementById( 'txtOut' );
  const childs = ul.getElementsByTagName( 'li' );
  var idx = -1, item;

  while( item = childs.item( ++idx ) ) {
//        console.log( typeof( item.dataset.nombre ), item.dataset.nombre );
    item.style.display = item.dataset['nombre'].startsWith( prefix ) ? 'initial' : 
'none';
  }
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias ! Y tiene cualquier idea para reproducir el css ?

Comment: No se mucho de `.css`, pero lo mas fácil es `Archivo / Guardar página WEB completa`. Te lo guarda todo en el disco, y tu ya puedes editar y modificar lo que quieras :-)